# When passing 2 identical Parcable Classes, 1 is null

Tags: android, parcelable

i have a weird issue.
I'm trying to pass 2 parcable classesfrom one activity to another.
I define both of them the exact same way, but of them is null.

The parcable class :

```
class Friends implements Parcelable {
private ArrayList<Integer> ids = new ArrayList<Integer>();

private ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
private ArrayList<Bitmap> images = new ArrayList<Bitmap>();

public void addId(Integer id)
{
    ids.add(id);
}
public void addName(String name){
    names.add(name); 
}

public void addImage(Bitmap img){
    images.add(img);
}
public ArrayList<Integer> getIds() {
    return ids;
}

public ArrayList<String> getNames() {
    return names;
}
public ArrayList<Bitmap> getImages() {
    return images;
}
@Override
public int describeContents() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}
@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    dest.writeList(ids);
    dest.writeList(names);
    dest.writeList(images);

}
  public static final Parcelable.Creator<Friends> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<Friends>() {
        public Friends createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new Friends(in);
        }
        public Friends[] newArray(int size) {
            return new Friends[size];
        }
    };
public Friends(Parcel in){
 in.readList(ids, null);
 in.readList(names, null);
 in.readList(images, null);
}
public Friends(Integer id, String name, Bitmap img) {
    ids.add(id);
    names.add(name);
    images.add(img);
}
public Friends(){

}
```

The Sending part :

```
          for(Integer position : selectedIds)
      {

            String name = a.getItem(position).getFriendName();
            int id = a.getItem(position).getFriendId();
            Bitmap img = a.getItem(position).getFriendImage();
            Log.e("ID",String.valueOf(id));
            selectedFriends.addId(new Integer(id));
            selectedFriends.addName(name);
            selectedFriends.addImage(img);



      }
      for(int position=0;position<list.getCount(); position++)
      {
            String name = a.getItem(position).getFriendName();
            int id = a.getItem(position).getFriendId();
            Bitmap img = a.getItem(position).getFriendImage();
            Log.e("All IDs",String.valueOf(id));
            allFriends.addId(new Integer(id));
            allFriends.addName(name);
            allFriends.addImage(img);
      }
      b.putParcelable("selecet_friends", selectedFriends);
      b.putParcelable("all_friends", allFriends);
      data.putExtras(b);
```

Both of the loops are being runned ( i can see the logs), all variables you don't see are being initialized correctly, everything is fine.

**The Reciving part :**
i define both as null :

```
    private Friends selectedFriends = null;
private Friends allFriends = null;
```

And handle the onResult like this :

```
                Log.e("Result","yessss");
            Friends all_friends = (Friends)data.getParcelableExtra("all_friends");
            Friends selected_friends = (Friends)data.getParcelableExtra("selected_friends");
            allFriends = all_friends;
            selectedFriends = selected_friends;
            if(selectedFriends != null){
                Log.e("is null","No");
            }
            if(allFriends != null){
                Log.e("is all null","No");
            }
```

Does anyone know how come the selectedFriends is null when allFriends is not?

**EDIT:**
Just a thought, but maybe it's because i put 2 parcables on a Bundle?
just i just add 2 bundles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the sending method you have a typo in this line:

```
b.putParcelable("selecet_friends", selectedFriends);
```

try this instead:

```
b.putParcelable("selected_friends", selectedFriends);
```

Also, you should use more specific names for the keys. The documentation for putExtras() says:

> *Add a set of extended data to the intent. The keys must include a
>   package prefix, for example the app com.android.contacts would use
>   names like "com.android.contacts.ShowAll*

Comment: Wow, did not see that one. Thank you! i will accept your answer but please edit it and add this from the putExtras documentation : "Add a set of extended data to the intent. The keys must include a package prefix, for example the app com.android.contacts would use names like "com.android.contacts.ShowAll".
In case someone encoutres the same problem, the names i've given are not good.

Comment: Done. And glad to be of help.